# Python: How can I pass and use variable in function?

Tags: python, string, list, function, parameter-passing

Is it possible to pass a variable (e.g. string) to function in python a later use it as a name of a list? How can I convert it?

```
def compare(string_variable, filename):
        with open(filename) as fr:
            for line in fr:
                variable.writelines(line)

compare(string_variable , filename)
```

## —— edit ——

this isn't the full code, it's not even the actual code as I wanted to simplify it in order to make my question as narrow as possible. I see I made a stupid mistake writing string.writlines etc. Below is the corrected version in pseudo code made really fast, so sorry if I made any mistakes

What I'm trying to do is pass a string variable to a function, use this variable as a list, append lines to it and save it in memory for later comparisons. this would be done thorugh a loop based on dict key: value, so I want my list to have the name like key value from the dict in order to generated a differently named list each time I go through a loop.

something like:

```
x = {
    key: value
    key2: value2
    }

def compare(key, filename):
        with open(filename) as fr:
            for line in fr.readlines():
                key_but_as_list.append(line)

for key in x.keys()
    compare(key, filename)
```

Do you get my idea now?

Comment: Yes it is possible. But first why?

Comment: I am looping through a dict that has "type": "filename"

Comment: Your code has a lot of errors actually. variable is undefined, writelines is a file attribute, you cannot just iterate over fr and so on. What are you trying to do?

Comment: There are plenty of excellent guides for learning basic Python

Comment: dude, this answer is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is ,

```
var='Hello'
def some_fun(var):
   var=[]
   var.append('Something')
   print var
some_fun(var)
```

Comment: This example is quite bad; whatever value `var` has upon passing as an argument, it will be se set to empty list in the method's scope, appended with that string and "Something" will be printed. Always; regardless what's the value of `var`.

Comment: This is just an example if the string variable can be used as a list or not, now on how to use it ,the scope(if throughout the code), that remains for the user to improvise on ,this is just a hardcoded version